# Is there a way to get rid of the \n\n character after converting a PDF with slate?

Tags: python, replace, newline

I am using Slate to convert a PDF to text but when I convert it to a string it prints new line characters `\n\n` between just about every line. I have tried just about everything to remove it but Python does not seem to recognize that it is there.

I have tried `.replace("\n\n", " ")` and `.split("\n\n")` and `.splitlines()` as well as just about every combination/differentiation of those including windows version of newline `\r\n`.

I am using Spyder as a compiler but I have tested printing to a text file as well to be sure it wasn't just the console.

```
def Submit():
    MakeDirs()
    newlineChar = '\n\n'
    global EOD_text
    global EODFilname
    with open(EODFilename, 'rb') as EODF:
        EOD_text = str(slate.PDF(EODF))
        EOD_text = EOD_text.replace("\n\n"," ")

    print(EOD_text)
```

Example Output:

```
["End Of Day Report\n\nFor Sunday, 12/29/2019\n\nDivision Sales\n\nTotal Sales\n\nDivision\n\nOnline Sales\n\nGeneral Information\n\nDay Temp:\n\nNight Weather:\n\nNight Temp:\n\nOpening Mgr:\n\nClosing Mgr:\n\nNotes:\n\nDay Weather:\n\nCategory Sales\n\nCategory/Sub-Category\n\nTotal Sales\n\nConcessions\n\n
```

Comment: Could you try "\\n\\n"?

Comment: I would recommend that you recognise that EOD_text is list like and perform a replace on each element of the list.

Comment: Can you explain why? @Nathan

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Also, is your output a list? If so, it's missing a square bracket.

Comment: I'm voting to close this since I can't reproduce the issue on the current output, and there isn't enough here to reproduce OP's program exactly.

Comment: Is the output cleaner if you use: EOD_text = slate.PDF(EODF).text() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this problem you have a piece of text with the `\n\n` characters like this:

```
example_text = 'example text \n\n example text'
```

Which you would like to remove. The easiest way to do this is:

```
print(example_text.replace('\n\n', '')
```

Which works fine for me, but does not for you for some reason. I assume (but cannot verify) that in your text the `\n` actually contains an escaped `\`, so it actually says `\\n`. This for instance could be the case if you're reading a text file which contains the text `\n\n`. In order to replace these, you use:

```
print(example_text.replace('\\n\\n', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Nathan got it to work with the suggestion to add a second \ in front of each \n. I believe Python was reading the "\n\n" as 2 newline character instead of a text string.